# Charm bar doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I have an issue with a charm bar not scrolling the bottom of the selection. This is what I see when I do https://postimg.cc/GBtP6vmc

I know the issue is caused because i'm using a fixed position of 92px from the top. If I change the .charms to top:0 the scroll behaves as expected however this isn't an option. Can the code below be fixed to scroll and look like this ? https://postimg.cc/8J0rWYRW

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
#logobanner{
    height:92px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color:black;
    }   

.charms{
    box-sizing: content-box; 
    position:fixed;
    top: 92px;
    left: 0px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #27383f;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100vh;
    min-height:100%;
        }

.sideicon1{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image: url(../images/user_dash.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 45px 45px; 
    }
.sideicon1title{
    color: #7f7f7f;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }       
.sidewrap1:hover .sideicon1{
    background-image: url(../images/user_dash_white.png);   
    }
.sidewrap1:hover .sideicon1title{
    color:#c9c9c9;
    }       
/* Customer Button */   
.sideicon2{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image:url(../images/customer_service.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 45px 45px; 
    }
.sideicon2title{
    color: #7f7f7f;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }       
.sidewrap2:hover .sideicon2{
    background-image:url(../images/customer_service_white.png); 
    }
.sidewrap2:hover .sideicon2title{
    color:#c9c9c9;
    }   
/* Post Button */   
.sideicon3{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image:url(../images/icon_post.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 45px 45px; 
    }
.sideicon3title{
    color: #7f7f7f;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }       
.sidewrap3:hover .sideicon3{
    background-image:url(../images/icon_post_white.png);    
    }
.sidewrap3:hover .sideicon3title{
    color:#c9c9c9;
    }   
/* Settings Button */   
.sideicon4{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image:url(../images/icon_settings.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 45px 45px; 
    }
.sideicon4title{
    color: #7f7f7f;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }       
.sidewrap4:hover .sideicon4{
    background-image:url(../images/icon_settings_white.png);    
    }
.sidewrap4:hover .sideicon4title{
    color:#c9c9c9;
    }
/* Logout Button */ 
.sideicon5{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image:url(../images/icon_logout.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 45px 45px; 
    }
.sideicon5title{
    color: #7f7f7f;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }       
.sidewrap5:hover .sideicon5{
    background-image:url(../images/icon_logout_white.png)   
    }
.sidewrap5:hover .sideicon5title{
    color:#c9c9c9;
    }               
.lefticonsdivider{
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#27393d;
    }   
.lefticonsdivider1{
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#36454a;
    }   




</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="logobanner"></div>


<div class="charms">
<a href="dash.php">
<div class='sidewrap1'>
<div class="sideicon1"></div>
<div class="sideicon1title">User Dash</div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider"></div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider1"></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="2.php">
<div class='sidewrap2'>
<div class="sideicon2"></div>
<div class="sideicon2title">Customers</div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider"></div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider1"></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="3.php">
<div class='sidewrap3'>
<div class="sideicon3"></div>
<div class="sideicon3title">Post</div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider"></div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider1"></div>
</div>
</a>


<a href="4.php">
<div class='sidewrap4'>
<div class="sideicon4"></div>
<div class="sideicon4title">Settings</div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider"></div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider1"></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="logout.php">
<div class='sidewrap5'>
<div class="sideicon5"></div>
<div class="sideicon5title">Logout</div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider"></div>
<div class="lefticonsdivider1"></div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/26zjybax/

Comment: You should put content below in some container, and shrink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use

> calc()

in height property.

For example:

```
.charms {
  height: calc(100% - 92px);
}
```

I hope that I helped.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any content below, thats why you can't see them all. Those css you have does trick the website that it has more content below, but you don't have any.

This will do the trick for now:

```
.charms{
box-sizing: content-box; 
position:fixed;
top: 92px;
left: 0px;
max-height: 75%;
background-color: #eee;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #27383f;
width: 25%;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Just replace your css with the css here above. 
If you have content below, you can set the max-height back to to 100%.